# Html - Issue with video poster

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

```
<video id="bgvid" controls >
   <source src="video/careers-video.mp4" poster="https://netbramha.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/netbramha-new/images/thumbnail-video@3x.jpg" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Hey guys I'm trying to put a poster. But it doesn't work. I have pasted my code above and I'm using a plugin for customizing video. The code I used for this is correct?

In this link you can see the same plugin. http://www.responsivedad.com/.

Thanks :)

Comment: try image with other format as `.png` instaed `.jpgf`

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="bgvid" controls poster="https://netbramha.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/netbramha-new/images/thumbnail-video@3x.jpg">
   <source src="video/careers-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

poster attribute is attribute of video tag. this might be work

Answer (score 0):

1. You use extention of image as `jpgf` that thae reason that the image does not load so use `.jpg` (without `f`)
2. use code with `source tag` [as here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp)

```css
video{
width:300px;
height:250px
}
```

```html
<video controls poster="https://netbramha.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/netbramha-new/images/thumbnail-video@3x.jpg">
  <source src="video/careers-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: tell me for more help:)